# How do I make a tellraw command say someone's name?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I need help here, I am making a map called "The Firing". I want it to say: `Welcome to The Firing, [USERNAME]`

What I had was

`/tellraw @a {"rawtext":[{"text":"Welcome to The Firing, !"]}, {["extra":[{"selector":"@p"}]}]}`

It did not work. Please help me here.

Answer (score 2):

You are so close, but you need to remove `extra`, it is not correct. Use multiple components instead:

```
tellraw @p {"rawtext":[{"text":"Welcome to the Firing, "},{"selector":"@p"},{"text":"!"}]}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This really means a lot!

Comment: @BraveGamerTVonBedrock Don't forget to click the check button next to the answer that helped you the most, to mark this question as solved.